provide http interceptor via a provider function
In my library, I export a http interceptor.
Currently to activate the interceptor, the user must use the following code:
import { provideNgProgressHttp, progressInterceptor } from 'ngx-progressbar/http';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    provideHttpClient(
      withInterceptors([progressInterceptor])
    ),
    provideNgProgressHttp()
  ]
});

I would like to avoid the withInterceptors([progressInterceptor]) part, and make it internally when user provide provideNgProgressHttp(). is this possible?
Expected usage:
import { provideNgProgressHttp } from 'ngx-progressbar/http';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    provideHttpClient(),
    provideNgProgressHttp()
  ]
});

Here is my code:
The interceptor function
export function progressInterceptor(req: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandlerFn): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
  return next(req).pipe(
    finalize(() => {
      // Some code
    })
  );
}

The provider function
export const NG_PROGRESS_HTTP_CONFIG: InjectionToken<NgProgressHttpConfig> = new InjectionToken<NgProgressHttpConfig>('ngProgressHttpConfig');

export function provideNgProgressHttp(config?: NgProgressHttpConfig): Provider {
  return [
    {
      provide: NG_PROGRESS_HTTP_CONFIG,
      useValue: config
    }
  ];
}


Hi, Yes it should be possible. You have to modify your provideNgProgressHttp so that it returns a list of providers that include both the existing NG_PROGRESS_HTTP_CONFIG provider and interceptor provider. Could look something like this : export function provideNgProgressHttp(config?: NgProgressHttpConfig): Provider[] { return [ { provide: NG_PROGRESS_HTTP_CONFIG, useValue: config }, { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useFactory: () => progressInterceptor, multi: true } ]; } 

@LaughByte Better not to write an answer as comment. but no I don't think this would work this is an interceptor function

This is not possible and this is by design. The HTTP_INTERCEPTORS token is not exposed.
This was a deliberate design choice of the new API; interceptors are sensitive to ordering and the registration of the HTTP services to actually consider those interceptors, so the API was designed such that both ordering and the registration is determined in a single place.
What you should do in your case, you should have a function that returns a list of interceptors, and it should be passed directly to provideHttpClient().
provideHttpClient(withInterceptors([...ngProgressHttpInterceptors()]))),

